# Check if any value is 0 in Python DataFrame

Tags: python, pandas

I have some csv files like:

```
Time   Test Two Three Five Six Seven Eight Nine Ten Eleven Twelve Thirteen  Fifteen  Sixteen   
0       0   0    0    0   0     0    0     0   -0.3   0     0       100        0       0   
0.02    0   0    0    0   0     0    0     0  -0.1   0.05   0       99        28       0   
0.04    0   0    0    0   0     0    0     0  -0.15  0.05   0.9    99.6      28.7      0   
...
```

My Code looks like:

```
list_of_dfs = [pandas.read_csv(filename) for filename in filenames]
for i in list_of_dfs:
    if any(x is 0 for x in i.Test):
        print("true")
    else:
        print("false")
```

This shows me only false (even i.Test is always 0)

```
print(list_of_dfs[0].Test)
```

shows

```
0      0
1      0
2      0
3      0
4      0
5      0
6      0
7      0
8      0
9      0
10     0
..
655    0
656    0
657    0
658    0
659    0
660    0
661    0
662    0
663    0
664    0
665    0
Name: Test, Length: 666, dtype: int64
```

Shouldn't be

```
any(x is 0 for x in i.Test)
```

always true as I have in every i.Test minimum one "0" (as they contain only 0s)

What is my mistake?

Comment: Use `x==0` instead of `x is 0`

Comment: `i.Test` is not `int` datatype. verify by `print(i.Test)`

Comment: Even better, broadcast the test over the series instead of looping in a generator expression: `df.i == 0` is a Series of boolean values, and `(df.i == 0).any()` is true if any of those values are true. Or, since 0 is falsey and all other numbers are truthy, you can use `not df.i.all()` to get the same effect more efficiently (but probably less readably).

Comment: with [mcve] code for one file with delimiter ',' I couldn't reproduce the issue. The above code returns `true` as long as all Test values are int and not float and not str

Comment: @Prateek I verified that that list_of_dfs[0].Test is an int64 Datatype i.Test should be the same in this case.
I try to provide a minimal non working example. But it would be too much to upload the thousands of csv files

Comment: @RafaelC x==0 fixed the issue. Thanks a lot

Comment: @abarnert `(i.Test == 0).any()` had the same results for me like `any(x == 0 for x in i.Test)`
However I can imagine that your method is more efficient. Could I also calculate the mean of a DataFrame? Like The mean of i.Thirteen?

Comment: @ChrizZlyBear Yes. Under the covers, each Series (column) is a numpy array, which means you can get all the simplicity and performance benefits of using numpy on them. (Assuming they’re numeric columns, that is; if they have `dtype=object` you don’t get much performance benefits, and for some complex types it’s often simpler to use pandas high-level functions, or even `apply`/`map`, than to drop down to numpy.) So you can get the mean by calling `sum()` on it then dividing by the len, or by using… I think it’s `scipy.stats.mean(i.Thirteen)`, but you can look it up.

Comment: Meanwhile, if you want to understand the difference between `is` and `==`, the docs page and/or relevant SO questions can be hard to search for, so let me know and I can find a link. But the short answer is that `a is b` is only true if `a` and `b` are *the same object*, and a pandas `int64` object will never be the same object as a built in `int` object, while `==` checks whether they have the same *value*, whether they’re the same object or two different objects that happen to be equal. You almost never want `is` with numbers, but you often want it with special singleton values like `None`.

Comment: @abarnert I just realised how much I can do with that method. Not only in that case. But this shortened 4 other complex for loops into one liners. and numpy/SciPy are not even easier. I guess they are way more efficient too. This helped me a lot too.

Answer (score 1):

The problem statement, if I understand correctly, is to return a value *for each dataframe* in a list depending on whether a 0 exists in each dataframe's `Test` series.

Simply printing `'true'` or `'false'` may not be enough, since you will then have to link these back to your list of dataframes. I recommend, instead, to use a dictionary to store your dataframes:

```
dict_of_dfs = {fn: pd.read_csv(fn) for fn in filenames}
```

Then you can use a dictionary comprehension to map each filename to a Boolean value according to your condition:

```
res = {fn: (df['test'] == 0).any() for fn, df in dict_of_dfs.items()}
```

You can then determine *which* dataframes fulfil your condition by either iterating `res.items()` or specifying a specific filename via `res['myfile.csv']`.

Notice that we are using vectorised operations rather than iterating each element in a series one at a time. This is a feature of Pandas and separates it from the standard Python list comprehension or generator expression method which you have been attempting. Vectorised operations give efficient access to contiguous memory blocks and should be preferred wherever possible.